# How to push small button with plastic cover on phone's edge easier?

Tags: phone, plastics

My phone (Xperia M4 Aqua) has a power button on the edge of the phone. After having a thin plastic cover, the button is required a lot of force to push it. I can cut a hole in the cover in that position, but I would like to have a non-irreservable solution.

Since I mostly use my phone with my left hand to be able to do other activities simultaneously, the button is pushed by the inner side of the index finger. Pushing it with nail is possible, but it will slow down my access to the phone, and adding a cognition workload by having to keep in mind how to push it. Is there a way to press it **without having to aware how the push should be**?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Perhaps it is intended to be difficult to press, to avoid pressing it by accident.

Comment: @KiranLinsuain I don't believe so. The thin plastic cover is likely a 3rd-party protective case, so making the buttons harder to use is not likely intentional. I have the same problem with my rubberized protective case, so I did the "cut out a hole" thing to fix it.

Comment: You should  put a tiny metal bar that fits inside cover so you can push that small button easily with that ?

Comment: @melic great idea. I'm looking for one now. If you know where to get one please share

Comment: @Ooker do you have any old pen/pencil which had metal hanger on it ? You may cut and use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an edge of a blister pack to insert to the cover:

[image]

## Advantages:

- No movement when pressed, due to its long residue
- No need to adjust its thickness
- Available everywhere, easy to replace if it ever breaks

Answer (score 1):

Simple question, simple answer....

Thumb-nail, rather than thumb.

Concentrated force in a small area, so you're not spending most of your effort pressing the case.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it again

Answer (score 1):

You could try use a very small piece of bluetack / whitetack or small slither of rubber band inside the case over the button area, this will increase the pressure to the button without the need for additional pressure from your finger/nails.

Adjust the amount of tack/rubber/alternative until you find the most suitable amount of pressure required for the task of operating the button.